# Graph Simplification Algorithm Advice Needed

Tags: algorithm, graph, simplification, lang, douglas-peucker

I have a need to take a 2D graph of n points and reduce it the r points (where r is a specific number less than n). For example, I may have two datasets with slightly different number of total points, say 1021 and 1001 and I'd like to force both datasets to have 1000 points. I am aware of a couple of simplification algorithms: Lang Simplification and Douglas-Peucker. I have used Lang in a previous project with slightly different requirements.

The specific properties of the algorithm I am looking for is:

1) must preserve the shape of the line

2) must allow me reduce dataset to a specific number of points

3) is relatively fast

This post is a discussion of the merits of the different algorithms. I will post a second message for advice on implementations in Java or Groovy (why reinvent the wheel).

I am concerned about requirement 2 above. I am not an expert enough in these algorithms to know whether I can dictate the exact number of output points. The implementation of Lang that I've used took lookAhead, tolerance and the array of Points as input, so I don't see how to dictate the number of points in the output. This is a critical requirement of my current needs. Perhaps this is due to the specific implementation of Lang we had used, but I have not seen a lot of information on Lang on the web. Alternatively we could use Douglas-Peucker but again I am not sure if the number of points in the output can be specified.

I should add I am not an expert on these types of algorithms or any kind of math wiz, so I am looking for mere mortal type advice :) How do I satisfy requirements 1 and 2 above? I would sacrifice performance for the right solution.

Comment: With 2d graph you mean something like `y=f(x)` approximated with a list of `(x, y)` pairs where `x[i] < x[i+1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find my C++ implementation and article on Douglas-Peucker simplification [here](http://psimpl.sourceforge.net) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/PolylineSimplification.aspx). I also provide a modified version of the Douglas-Peucker simplification that allows you to specify the number of points of the resulting simplified line. It uses a priority queue as mentioned by 'Peter Taylor'. Its a lot slower though, so I don't know if it would satisfy the '*is relatively fast*' requirement.

I'm planning on providing an implementation for Lang simplification (and several others). Currently I don't see any easy way how to adjust Lang to reduce to a fixed point count. If you 
could live with a less strict requirement: '*must allow me reduce dataset to an **approximate**  number of points*', then you could use an iterative approach. Guess an initial value for lookahead: point count / desired point count. Then slowly increase the lookahead until you approximately hit the desired point count.

I hope this helps.

p.s.: I just remembered something, you could also try the Visvalingam-Whyatt algorithm. In short:
-compute the triangle area for each point with its direct neighbors
-sort these areas
-remove the point with the smallest area
-update the area of its neighbors
-resort
-continue until n points remain

Comment: Thanks a bunch Elmar. I'm not familiar with Visvalingam-Whyatt but will check it out.I think given the nature of the systems I am writing I am going to want to know all the graph simplification routines and their relative pros and cons.

Comment: you might want to start with the article: "Performance Evaluation of Line Simplification Algorithms", available using this link: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.5882&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think you can adapt Douglas-Pücker quite straightforwardly. Adapt the recursive algorithm so that rather than producing a list it produces a tree mirroring the structure of the recursive calls. The root of the tree will be the single-line approximation P0-Pn; the next level will represent the two-line approximation P0-Pm-Pn where Pm is the point between P0 and Pn which is furthest from P0-Pn; the next level (if full) will represent a four-line approximation, etc. You can then trim the tree either on the basis of depth or on the basis of distance of the inserted point from the parent line.

Edit: in fact, if you take the latter approach you don't need to build a tree. Instead you populate a priority queue where the priority is given by the distance of the inserted point from the parent line. Then when you've finished the queue tells you which points to remove (or keep, according to the order of the priorities).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I haven't loop back to this problem yet but it seems like your response shows me how to get Douglas-Pücker to return a specific set of points. This is a very valuable feature for my needs.